# Copy from worksheet to another workbook keeping format and paste value

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook with multiple sheets. I am trying to copy from one workbook to another but i want to remove formulas but keep the values

this is the code i have so far

```
Sub SplitEachWorksheet()
Dim FPath As String
FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

If ws.Name = "Agent1" Or ws.Name = "Agent2"  Then
    


    ws.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & "Agents" & "\" & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End If


Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have tried a couple of paste special lines but had no luck.
Any help would be greate

Comment: Looks a little bit odd, but just add the line `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value` after the `Copy`-command. This will replace all formulas with the actual value.

Comment: this worked thank you!